# How can I invoke a method in a UIView subclass, everytime the device rotates?

Tags: ios

I want to call a function in a UIView subclass of an item added to the main window, when the device rotate.

I've many items so I don't want to call such method one by one, but I want it automatically invoked for this item and all subviews.

thanks

Comment: You can try `NSNotificationcenter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the automatic subview behavior, declare a `UIView` category adding the method you wish to be invoked. Then have your view subscribe to device rotation notifications, and as part of its handling of the notification, call that same method on all its subviews. Something like this (typed without benefit of autocorrect or compiled, so please take as an illustration and not a full example program):

```
@interface UIView (MyAppAdditions)

- (void)rotationDetected;

@end

@implementation UIView (MyAppAdditions)

- (void)rotationDetected
{

}

@end


@implementation MyView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didRotate:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)didRotate:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [self rotationDetected];
    [self.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(rotationDetected)];
}

@end
```

A more flexible implementation would also override `initWithCoder:` or `awakeFromNib` to subscribe the rotation notification as well.